# C/C++ server not sending last few lines of file

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I am writing a simple server in C/C++. I have everything mostly complete, but there is one problem. The server fails to send the last three lines of a file to a client. I assume I am closing the socket connection prematurely, but my attempts to remedy this have failed. For example, calling

```
shutdown(clientSckt, SHUT_RDWR);
```

right before calling the close() method for the client socket. And adding a latency to the socket parameters like so:

```
struct linger l;
l.l_onoff = 1;
l.l_linger = 1;
setsockopt(clientSckt, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &l, sizeof(l));
```

after it has been opened. But neither of these seem to work. The server writes everything with no errors, but the client is not receiving everything.

Comment: Have you verified that every write is writing the amount of data being sent to it?  ie:  If you send n bytes to write, you need to verify that n bytes were written.  What does your receive code look like assuming the write is truly writing everything?

Comment: It says that it is writing the correct number of bytes to the socket. At this point, I am just using an external program to do the request (like a web browser).

Comment: Are you implementing a protocol the browser supports or how are you sending a file over?

Comment: Try changing the how option (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Closing-a-Socket.html) and/or try to flush() the handle before shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, I forgot to add the character length of the header to the length of the file I was sending over. Hence, the client was closing the connection before the server had sent everything over.

Answer (score 1):

From vague memory:
a) if you want to use SO_LINGER, use close().
b) more robust is do a half shutdown

```
shutdown(clientSckt, SHUT_WR)
```

and then read() until you get a 0.

Comment: Correct. The only way to know if the client "got it all" is for the client to either send some sort of "ack" or just wait until the client closes the connection. I would suggest having some sort of reasonable timeout (45-90 seconds) that closes the socket anyway so that a misbehaving client can't keep the socket open forever.

Comment: I agree with both @RON and selbie. Also read the very good [ultimate SO_LINGER page](http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable) which is already linked in many answers.